# Help with interface

Tags: linux, debian, networking, network-interface

I'm using debian image on virtualbox on bridge mode ( same issue with NAT network )
I'm tring to install Talos Os but i have issue with interface. Can you please tell me what's this interface `br-0bad60df5a4c` ?

```
osboxes@osboxes:~$ sudo talosctl cluster create
validating CIDR and reserving IPs
generating PKI and tokens
creating network talos-default
creating controlplane nodes
creating worker nodes
renamed talosconfig context "talos-default" -> "talos-default-2"
waiting for API
bootstrap error: 2 error(s) occurred:
        rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 10.5.0.2
        timeout
```

Interface :

```
osboxes@osboxes:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:a9:1d:5d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.29/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
       valid_lft 80005sec preferred_lft 80005sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fea9:1d5d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:79:fc:6b:1e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: br-0bad60df5a4c: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:c9:4f:9b:cf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.5.0.1/24 brd 10.5.0.255 scope global br-0bad60df5a4c
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:c9ff:fe4f:9bcf/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Also find this :

```
osboxes@osboxes:~$ sudo talosctl cluster create -?
unknown shorthand flag: '?' in -?

Usage:
  talosctl cluster create [flags]

Flags:
      --arch string                              cluster architecture (default "amd64")
      --bad-rtc                                  launch VM with bad RTC state (QEMU only)
      --cidr string                              CIDR of the cluster network (IPv4, ULA network for IPv6 is derived in automated way) (default "10.5.0.0/24")
```

Answer (score 1):

`br-0bad60df5a4c` is very probably a bridge interface. You can investigate its configuration with `brctl show br-0bad60df5a4c`.

Comment: `bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br-5cb55b273e75         8000.0242edba1f81       no `